# Regex for Replacing a subString in a String using ant

Tags: java, regex, ant

I've been struggling when trying to use regex in an ant file(using replaceregexp tag) to replace a specific string, which is not constant, in a java class, for example:
Replace:  V1_0_0 by V2_0_0
In:

```
public void doSomething() {
    return "xxxxxxxV1_0_0.yyyyyyyy"
}
```

And of course V1_0_0 will always change
And .yyyyyyyy will change but xxxxxxx will be the same

this is the closer I could get:
(?<=xxxxxxx).* or (?<=xxxxxxx).*

but this is what I get:

```
public void doSomething() {
    return "xxxxxxxV2_0_0;
}
```

xxxxxxx or yyyyyyyy can be any characters allowed in a java class name

Comment: what `xxxxxxx` and `yyyyyyyy` can be, digits, letters special character?

Comment: updated my question adding this info

Comment: Try `(xxxxxxx)V[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+` and replace with `\1V2_0_0`

Comment: didnt work, no changes in the original String

Comment: How did you use the regex?

Comment: inside replaceregexp tag like this match='(xxxxxxxxx)V[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+'

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to replace starting from V until the end of the string, so check this regex: ^[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+\..+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
(?:xxxxxxx)V[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+(?:\.[a-z]+)?
```

I made the `yyyyyy` part optional using the `?`.
Maybe you need a different character class than `a-z`, maybe `[a-zA-Z]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qI1vTx/1)

[Code Sample](https://ideone.com/FAJixB):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Ideone {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
  String regex = "(?:xxxxxxx)V[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+(?:\\.[a-z]+)?";
  String string = "public void doSomething() {\n" 
                + "    return \"xxxxxxxV1_0_0.yyyyyyyy\";\n" 
                + "}";
  String subst = "xxxxxxxV2_0_0";

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

  String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);
  System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
 }
}
```